# How to return an image out of imagePickerController?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm new to programming and Swift and I can't find a solution to my problem :

I have 4 UIImageView with an UIButton on top of each image.
When I tap a UIButton, I want to open an UIImagePickerController, select an image and place it in the UIImageView associated (here's a screen of my [Interface Builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znh2S.png))

I've placed my UIImageView in an outlet collection

```
@IBOutlet var layout1Images: [UIImageView]!
```

Here's my IBAction linked to my 4 buttons :

```
@IBAction func openImagePicker(_ sender: UIButton) {
    for image in layout1Images {
        if sender.tag == image.tag {
            
            let picker = UIImagePickerController()
            picker.allowsEditing = true
            picker.delegate = self
            present(picker, animated: true)
            
        }
    }
}
```

And my imagePickerController :

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    guard let image = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage else { return }
    
    //How to return the image to the selected UIImageView ?
            
    dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

How can I return the image to the selected UIImageView ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all store the tag you are getting from UIButton in a variable like

```
var selectedTag = 0
```

in `openImagePicker()` Action add the following line

```
selectedTag = sender.tag
```

now in `func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any])`

add this line

```
layoutImages[selectedTag].image = image
```

Answer (score -1):

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
       guard let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else {
                  fatalError("Expected a dictionary containing an image, but was provided the following: \(info)")
              }
// make use of the image
   }
```